# How to add certain rows of a pandas dataframe to a list based on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file, with one column labeled 'count', and then 10 columns, labeled 1-10. There are a total of 100 rows. For each of the ten columns, I would like to add all the values in that column, where the 'count' value is between 100-400, to a list. This would result in 10 lists. I have attached a sample of what the data looks like, and some code I have. Thank you[image]

Essentially, for each column, I would like a list of all the values where the 'count' value of that row is between 100-400. I would like to keep all of the lists in a dictionary, mapping the column header to the list of all values within the required interval.

So far, I have:

```
import pandas as pd
dict ={}
data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv') 
headers = data.columns.values
headers = headers[1:]
count = 1
for header in headers:
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        dict[str(count)] = []
        if 100<=data.loc[index, 'count'] <= 400:
            dict[str(count)].append(data.loc[index, header])
count+=1
```

But this seems to be crashing in jupyter notebook. Thank you!

Comment: Please try searching for an answer on Google before coming to StackOverflow. The answer to your question can be found here:

https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/02/how-to-subset-pandas-dataframe-based-on-values-of-a-column/

Comment: Thank you! I looked through that link, but did not find exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, conceptually, but you probably just want the in-built `pandas` function to help you do this: [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

````
# Get the data which falls into the range of interest
range_data = data[(100<=data['count'])&(data['count']<=400)]

# Convert column names to strings (rather than numbers)
range_data.columns = range_data.columns.astype(str)

# Convert to a dictionary
value_dict = range_data.drop(columns=['counts']).to_dict(orient='list')```
````

#### Range Comparisons

You are not going to be able to do this in python:

`100<=data.loc[index, 'count'] <= 400`

You need to keep every comparison separate, as follows:

`100<=data.loc[index, 'count'] and data.loc[index, 'count'] <= 400`

#### Naming

It's a bad idea to name your dictionary `dict`. That will over-ride the base function `dict` with your dictionary, so you won't be able to call `dict` to create a new dictionary anymore. Besides, it could be quite confusing.

Comment: Thank you! How do I make sure I am looping through each column and row? And for the dictionary, is this one dictionary for the entire dataset?

Comment: It's best to avoid loops when using `DataFrames`. You apply the mask on the first line:
`range_data = data[(100<=data['count'])&(data['count']<=400)]`
which is effectively dealing with all the rows at once.

Likewise, the `to_dict` function automatically deals with all columns at once.

The final dictionary contains the whole dataset of values with count between 100 and 400.